# Reference a local file instead of a remote file

Tags: javascript

I have some code that downloads a file from the internet located here:

http://www.amsat.org/amsat/ftp/keps/current/nasa.all

and performs certain calculations on it in order to determine a satellites location. Because of server issues which seem to prevent this file from being downloaded I want to move this file onto the local machine and reference it from there.

I know that javascript can't read .txt files without an ActiveX component involved but if I change the variable URL to reference the file would it work in the same way? I tried saving the file as a .txt, .all and a .xml file and the program fails. What am I doing wrong?

The code for getting the original file is below and the URL it looks to is above.

```
function getOrbitalElements()
{
TLE_Line1="";
TLE_Line2="";

pgTXT = "";

xmlhttp = null;

if ( window.XMLHttpRequest )
{
    xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
} 
else if ( window.ActiveXObject )
{
    xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject( "Microsoft.XMLHTTP" );
}

if( xmlhttp != null )
{ 
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = stateChange;
    xmlhttp.open("GET",url,true);
    xmlhttp.send(null);
}
}
```

Finally I moved the file to the same folder as the html file and removed any spaces in the file name to see if it makes a difference. Nothing seems to work - anyone got any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [File API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Using_files_from_web_applications).

> Using the File API added to the DOM in HTML5, it's now possible for
>   web content to ask the user to select local files, then read the
>   contents of those files. This selection can be done by either using an
>   HTML input element, or by drag and drop.

Comment: Thanks - I'll be using the FileAPI during the same program in the future

Answer (score 1):

Is Amsat.org a website controlled by you? If it is you should serve the textfile as something that makes more sense to javascript than a textfile (probably JSON).

If you dont control the domain, downloading the file via ajax is likely to be impossible. In that case you can download the file with your server (e.g. fopen in php or the respective function in your serverside language) and then serve it to the client. You should check the rights to do so with the website owner before doing that.

Comment: Cheers for the input.No I don't control Amsat. The answer above will prove useful in the future but I did solve my problem - I basically captured the necessary file as a text file and changed the extension to .all. This was necessary for the rest of the  program to work. I then placed it in the same folder as the main html file and it worked :P